# Переопределение стандартного стиля кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

вопрос в следующем: в моём приложении есть кнопка, стандартный стиль которой я успешно переопределил, всё работает замечательно кроме одного "но".

Когда кнопка получает фокус мышью - всё отлично, срабатывает `VisualState` `Focused` и рамка кнопки становится толще на один пиксель, но когда кнопка получает фокус от клавиатуры, то помимо увеличения толщины рамки появляется ещё и какая-то пунктирная обводка этой кнопки. **Как мне избавиться от этой обводки?**

Вот обычное состояние кнопки:

[image: Normal button]

Вот она получила фокус мышью:

[image: Focused button]

А вот тут она получила фокус от клавиши "Tab":

[image: Tab focused button]

Вот весь стиль кнопки(он довольно большой):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalControlBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NormalControlBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NormalBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.States>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource MouseOverControlBackgroundColor}"
                                                            Duration="0"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource MouseOverControlBorderColor}"
                                                            Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource PressedControlBackgroundColor}"
                                                            Duration="0"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource PressedControlBorderColor}"
                                                            Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="{StaticResource DisabledOpacity}"
                                                             Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup.States>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Normal"
                                                      To="MouseOver"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource MouseOverControlBackgroundColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource MouseOverControlBorderColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="MouseOver"
                                                      To="Pressed"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource PressedControlBackgroundColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource PressedControlBorderColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed"
                                                      To="MouseOver"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource MouseOverControlBackgroundColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource MouseOverControlBorderColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="MouseOver"
                                                      To="Normal"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource NormalControlBackgroundColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="{StaticResource NormalControlBorderColor}"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Enabled"
                                                      To="Disabled"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="{StaticResource DisabledOpacity}"
                                                             Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Disabled"
                                                      To="Enabled"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="{StaticResource NormalOpacity}"
                                                             Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.States>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)"
                                                                To="{StaticResource FocusedBorderThickness}"
                                                                Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)"
                                                                To="{StaticResource NormalBorderThickness}"
                                                                Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup.States>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Unfocused"
                                                      To="Focused"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)"
                                                                To="{StaticResource FocusedBorderThickness}"
                                                                Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Focused"
                                                      To="Unfocused"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.075">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)"
                                                                To="{StaticResource NormalBorderThickness}"
                                                                Duration="0:0:0.075"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.States>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.States>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: Не надо избавляться от этой обводки. Она показывает клавиатурный фокус.

Comment: @VTT, подскажите пожалуйста, как переопределить отображение клавиатурного фокуса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё гениальное просто:

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```